# symfony 1.4 - form validation if some field checked

Tags: forms, symfony1

Like in title. I need validate some fields only if some checkbox is choosen.
How can I do that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

use a `postValidator`.

see an example [here](http://symfony.com/blog/call-the-expert-how-to-implement-a-conditional-validator)

Comment: I've tried it and it works instead of every values is NULL. public function `checkTechOption($validator, $values)` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your function should return all the values after processing: `return $values;`